# Lubuntu -How to Add software to menu

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, menu

I'm new on Lubuntu and so I downloaded a editor like LightTable and it runs only with this command from command line

> ./LightTable

So HOW CAN I ADD THIS SOFTWARE ON MY MENU ?

Comment: @lese doesn't Lubuntu run LXDE rather than GNOME?

Comment: @roaima - LXDE uses `.desktop` files too.  There is also [LXShortCut](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXShortCut) which is a GUI that does the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could eg.: check what's inside your folder :

```
ls -la /usr/share/applications/
```

find a similar entry for an other text editor eg.:

```
# cat /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Sublime Text
Comment=Sublime Text 2
Exec=sublime_text
Icon=/opt/sublime/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;TextEditor;
```

copy and fix the content per your requirements eg:

```
cp -p /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop /usr/share/applications/lighttable.desktop
```

---

eg.:

```
# cat /usr/share/applications/lighttable.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Light Table
Comment=Light Table
Exec=/path/to/your/executable/script/LightTable
Icon=/path/to/your/icon/Light_Table.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;TextEditor;
```

Note: make sure your GUI user has execute permissions on the `LightTable` script